# How to set a path to virtual environment for sublime text 3 plugin to work correctly

Tags: python, django, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I am trying to install a plugin called "Django manage commands" in sublime text 3. and after installation, I got the following message

```
Remember to set the path to the directory where your virtual environments are installed in "python_virtualenv_paths" for the plugin to work correctly, as many directories as you need can be added.
```

How can I do this? I found the same message in other plugins as well.I use Debian Linux
Thanks for your time in advance '_'